# Boolean result from hashtable with another Boolean

Tags: vb.net, hashtable

I have some inherited code that has something in it I have never seen, do not understand and can't find anything about. Essentially it is:

```
                Dim h As Hashtable
                Dim a As Boolean
                Dim b As Boolean
                a = h(b)
```

The last line is the one that is totally throwing me. It is setting a Boolean to a Hashtable  that, somehow has a different Boolean tacked on the end. I am guessing it might be some kind of implied data type assignment or logic operation? There is no array, or collection of the hashtable object.

I am not familiar with this. Can anyone point me in a direction, please?

Comment: Please supply a minimum *working* code sample.

Comment: That sample will function. I just cannot figure out what the hell it is doing.

Comment: Ah, I should have also said code that compiles with Option Strict On. And it doesn't work as-is even with the setting Off because `h` is not initialized.

Comment: Never mind. A hash table is essentially the same as a collection. The (b) is functioning as an element pointer. A stupid way to do that kind of thing, I think.
--I think this project may actually be the one that makes me completely insane.

Thanks for making me look at it a 57th time to get it.

Answer (score 1):

A hash table is essentially the same as a collection. The (b) is functioning as an element pointer. A stupid way to do that kind of thing, I think. Thanks to @AndrewMorton for making me look at it a 57th time to get it.

--I think this project may actually be the one that makes me completely insane.